# Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath] Flutterfire

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to get some information from a document in firebase. I have done it multiple times but this time I am getting a weird error

```
Error: Assertion failed: file:///E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-2.2.1/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:69:12
field is String || field is FieldPath
"Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]"
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:4351:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:4294:15)
    at platform_interface_document_snapshot.DocumentSnapshotPlatform.new.get (http://localhost:61463/packages/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_write_batch.dart.lib.js:651:66)
    at cloud_firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.__.get (http://localhost:61463/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart.lib.js:713:73)
    at cloud_firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.__._get (http://localhost:61463/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart.lib.js:716:19)
    at emailLogIn (http://localhost:61463/packages/xspectre/Login/DarkSignUp.dart.lib.js:35657:105)
    at emailLogIn.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:37968:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:37822:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:32783:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:33331:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:33369:17)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:33094:27)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:38083:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:38089:13)
    at http://localhost:61463/dart_sdk.js:33586:9
```

I have pinpointed the error to this line where it is retrieving a field from the document

```
      await prefs.setString('nickname', documents[0]['nickname']);
```

I  have no idea why this error is coming. I am using cloud_firestore 14.4

This is the full code of how I get the data

```
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email',isEqualTo: user.email.toString()).get();
      DocumentSnapshot documents = snapshot.docs[0];
      prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString('nickname', documents[0]['nickname'.toString()].toString());
      await prefs.setString('email',  documents[0]['email'.toString()].toString());
      await prefs.setString('photo',  documents[0]['photo'].toString());
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Home.route);
```

Note that the error occurs in all the similar lines
My main goal is to log a user in with firebase email/password authentication and get his/her data from their firestore document

Comment: Please edit the question to show some more context around that line of code.  It's hard to read because we don't know what `documents` is.  Ideally, there should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the issue by copying what you provide.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the suggestion. I have done that. All the .toString() was done to try and fix the problem but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using another integer index on `documents`.  You've already pulled the first document from the query results with `snapshot.docs[0]`.  If you want to start getting fields from that one document, just start indexing it with the strings of the field names you want.

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = snapshot.docs[0];
String nickname = snapshot["nickname"];
```

You should also check to see if there even are any documents at all before you start indexing into the array.  It's very possible that a query could return 0 documents.

Comment: I'm so dumb. I did not even realize I was doing that. I'll check and let you know if it worked. Its just that I am used to writing get requests with double square brackets that I did not notice I had done it twice

Comment: Older versions sort of forced you to at times, after one of the updates, I had to go through and change old code.